# Sorting child item of navigation menu using code in wordpress

Tags: menus

I am adding product category as a new child menu in main parent 
"Categories" menu at front.but they are not sorted.When i am adding new child menu its gets a last position in menu. But i want to sort them and display in alphabetically order.
For adding new child used wp_update_nav_menu_item method and getting all menus using wp_get_nav_menu_items method. 
Any one can help me. I am working on this last 8 days

Comment: wp_get_nav_menu_items receives $args parameter, and you can use 'orderby' option. [here is official documents](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)